# pyodbc - Error - Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found

Tags: pyspark, databricks, pyodbc

When trying to connect to sql server, below is the error thrown in Databricks

> Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wen0p.png)

It does not happen always, but once in a while this error is thrown.

Can some one please help in saying why this happens and how to resolve.

Comment: which databricks are you using? azure,aws or community?

Comment: @JayashankarGS Azure Databricks